# RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider in Blazor app without identi Identity

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to build  Blazor server side app using [cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1). I did manage to get authentication following sample above.
In my app I skipped `services.AddIdentity` and app working so far without problems, I am able to  login, logout, determine user roles and others.

What I am not quite sure that I understand is `RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider` class and its service, `services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<AppUser>>();`

Does Blazor app need this service to continue communicating with client, or it is just security barrier?
I am ok to client remains logged in as long as cookie is not expire.
If I need `RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider` service how I can confirm that user is valid from passed  `AuthenticationState`? (looking in claim or something else).

Comment: I just ran into an Example Implementation of RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider.  

The Route I took was by using AuthenticationStateProvider. It still seems a bit counter-intuitive. However, I am able to manually validate a Token or Cookie by doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here,

> protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

means, in every 30 minutes, this mechanism will call **ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync** to check whether current auth is valid or not.